# Block a queue from receiving message in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ as the message bus for the components in my system to talk to each other. For some reasons, I'd like to stop the publishers from sending messages to a queue/exchange for a while and resume them later. Could you please suggest a way to make it happen? I've been reading on writing rabbitMQ pluggins but as I know very little about Erlang, I'm not sure that it can do what I'm expecting.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Add some usecase example of what you are trying to achieve, what's your configuration etc.. You can just stop your producer code from sending message or as Derick suggested you can remove the queue binding. You need to give more information for proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can :

1. Use this plug-in https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange to delay the messages
2. Stop the publish client side, store them in a list and then publish after the time you want

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to stop the publishers from sending messages to a queue/exchange for a while and resume them later.

If you don't care about losing messages, you only need to remove the exchange -> queue bindings for the queues in question. this will prevent messages from being routed to the queues.

if you need to "resume" receiving messages where you left off, you can't do that. a queue either receives a message or it doesn't, when the message is initially published. for example, you publish message 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. after message 3 publishes, you "stop" routing to the queue. later, you want to restart routing and receive message 4 and 5 in that same queue... that isn't possible.

if you need the "resume" option, your best bet is to stop your consumers and let the messages collect in the queue. re-start your consumer when you need to start processing messages again.